# How much does a drag chute system weight?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet, parachute

How much weight does a drag chute add to a plane?

Let's take the [Tu-114](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-104) as an example. This plane has a loaded weight of 68.1 tons (I could not find a max landing weight figure). I could not find how much it's drag chute system weighs.

One purpose of this question is to compare it to thrust reverser systems. I have [a separate question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43565/how-much-weight-does-a-thrust-reverser-add) on that.

Comment: Interesting comparison. However, remember that TRs stow themselves back into the nacelle after use. Drag chutes are discarded on the runway and need to be collected, repacked and reloaded on the aircraft. This fouls the runway for the next aircraft. They could be disconnected on the taxiway, but then they remain as FOD for the following craft.

Comment: _I see where you're headed..._ :)

Comment: @FreeMan Never knew that about discarding chutes on the runway. Yeah that seems unnecessarily...what's the word...unsophisticated? It makes me wonder if some tiny wind-up motor can reel the chute back in, then at the gate some rampies can repack it properly.

Comment: Drag chutes were basically designed for military use where you have lots of _Private power_ to handle things like this. Applying the use of chutes to civilian, commercial aircraft use would take a _lot_ of redesign, rethinking, and plenty of spares because you'd have to replace the "chute pack" between each flight and send the expended one off to be inspected & repacked. Plus, can you imagine all the foreheads smacking against the seat back when the chute is deployed? _hmmm, makes me want to see this happen just for the entertainment value!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the aircraft- for example, the the [brake parachute system of the 17t F-16 weighs 20 lbs](http://www.lifesupportintl.com/products/aircraft-deceleration/parachute-f-16-drogue/).

Generally, in an aircraft the brake chute system will weigh much less compared to the thrust reverser. While I'm not able to get any 'official values', [according to this thres](http://www.pprune.org/spectators-balcony-spotters-corner/409263-braking-parachute.html),

> In a Lear (24-25) the drag chute weighs some 25 lbs, the Dee Howard reversers weigh 350 lbs...

Comment: 20 pounds? Are you sure that's not the pilot's parachute that deploys after ejecting?

Comment: @Drz214, the link provided by aeroalias clearly refers to the drag chute.